# Mysql is truncating char(2) column values to 1 character

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I have a database of zipcodes in this format:

```
zip varchar(11)     
state char(2)                       
latitude varchar(10)            
longitude varchar(10)               
city varchar(50)                
full_state varchar(50)      
is_active tinyint(1)
```

I am importing a csv file into it. Everything loads fine
except for the `state(2)` field which instead of loading say, `MA` or `NY`, it
just loads it as one character, `M` and `N`. I am using a `mysql myisam` table and
using the PHPAdmin import feature. Any ideas on the possibilities causing this?

If you need more info let me know and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to ensure that your csv file doesn't have spaces around the state field.  For example, it should be like this:

`Cincinnati,OH,45241,USA`

and not

`Cincinnati, OH, 45241, USA`

If you could paste a few lines of your file it would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Right on the money seanbreeden! I renamed it with a `.txt` extension and say a leading space just as your example shows. Got rid of it, changed it back to a `.csv`, uploaded it an walah! Thank you sir!